# Ajax request to the same url

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have the following code:

```php
<?php
function isAjaxRequest() {
    return (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
}

var_dump(isAjaxRequest());

if (isAjaxRequest()) {
    echo json_encode(['ajax' => true]);
    exit(0);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    Test
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.get("/", function () {
                console.log(arguments);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd> (to close the tab) then <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+T</kbd> (to reopen the just-closed tab), I get JSON response instead of the HTML page.

Why is that?

Comment: It is reproducible in *Chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 m (64-bit)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you reopen a closed tab, the browser is allowed to reuse the data from cache for the given URL to populate the window. Since the data in cache is from the ajax request response, that's what it uses, and you see the JSON.

So that leads to the question: Why didn't the browser use the HTML from cache when satisfying the ajax request? Browsers use different rules to determine whether to use cached content depending on what they're doing. In this case, it appears Chrome is happy to reuse it when restoring the recently-closed tab, and not when doing the ajax request.

You can correct it by telling the browser to *never* cache the response. Whether that's desirable depends on your use case.

For instance, inserting these at the top of your file (after the opening `<?php` tag, of course) makes it not happen for me:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```